# Is Cellular Internet Connectivity lost when connecting to WiFi captive portals?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, captive-portal

Would it be expected that when connecting with a smartphone with cellular internet enabled, to a WiFi captive portal, smartphone "looses" cellular internet?

AFAIK captive portal either redirect HTTP or by DNS.

Maybe in some smartphones, they are allowed to have 2 connections (the captive and the cellular), and maybe some of them will choose the better connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the phone and this more related to connecting to wireless than captive portal.

Most devices I have seen keep the 3G/cellular service active, but set the data default route over the wifi. Monitoring data usage on my iphone for example shows 3g data is going up when on wifi, but, it is next to nothing.

Comment: I agree on what you say. What do you think would happen on most phones? Will they provide a fallback to 3G connection?

Comment: Well, if the wireless fails, it will go back to 3G on my iphone... but remember, every device can be different